# every 4 block another background color in a uicollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` with a list of `cells`. Each `cell` has a `backgroundColor`. So it should be like this.

- Cell 1 --> Red color
- Cell 2 --> Green color
- Cell 3 --> Orange color
- Cell 4 --> Yellow Color
- Cell 5 --> Red color
- Cell 6 --> Green color
- Cell 7 --> Orange color
- Cell 8 --> Yellow Color
- Cell 9 --> Red color
- Cell 10 --> Green color
- Cell 11 --> Orange color
- Cell 12 --> Yellow Color

At the moment I'm doing it like this. I've declared a `private int` in my `ViewController` and in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I do this.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //  MagazineCollectionViewCell *cell = (MagazineCollectionViewCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MagazineCollectionViewCell " forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ReisCategorieCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReisCategorieCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegationListener = self;

    Reiscategorie *category = [arrCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.reisCategorie = category;

    cell.lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dosis-Medium" size:35];
    cell.lblDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dosis-Medium" size:15];
    [cell.btnAanbod.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Dosis-Medium" size:23]];

    cell.lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.lblDescription.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.btnAanbod.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    cell.btnAanbod.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    countBackground++;
    if(countBackground>4){
        countBackground = 0;
    }
    if (countBackground == 1) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslRed];
        cell.btnAanbod.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslBrown];
    }else if (countBackground == 2){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslBrown];
        cell.btnAanbod.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslGray2];
    }else if (countBackground == 3){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslGray];
        cell.btnAanbod.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslBrown];
    }else if (countBackground == 4){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslGray2];
        cell.btnAanbod.backgroundColor = [UIColor aslBrown];
    }

    if([category.cat_name isEqualToString:@"Lapland"]){
        cell.btnLapland.hidden = NO;
    }else{
        cell.btnLapland.hidden = YES;
    }
    [cell.btnAanbod setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"btnAanbod", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.lblTitle.text = category.cat_name;
    cell.lblDescription.text = category.cat_description;
    return cell;
}
```

This works if you scroll slowly. But if you are scrolling to fast the colors are getting mixed up. So can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, please accept my answer below and close this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rely on `indexPath.row` instead of using manual cell counting. It doesn't work because your cells get reused while you scroll your `UICollectionView`.

Assuming that you have one section in your `UICollectionView`, you may use something like this to determine color for each cell:

```
switch (indexPath.row % 4) {
        case 0:
            // yellow
            break;
        case 1:
            // orange
            break;
        case 2:
            // green
            break;
        case 3:
            // red
            break;
    }
```

I haven't tested this logic, but this general approach should work.

Comment: You should say indexPath.row %4. But I got the colors right. The only problem is I think with the reuse of cells.

Comment: It sets the colors right. But when you scroll too fast it goes wrong. I think that is a problem with the resuable cells

Comment: This is strange behaviour, theoretically it should work no matter how fast you scroll because color assigning happens almost immediately (you don't need to do anything asynchronously) and you should return correct reusable cell for asked `indexPath`. Any idea why it may actually happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
if(countBackground>4){
    countBackground = 0;
}
```

You set `countBackground` to 0 and don't increment in the cell after that. A soulution would be to use `countBackground = 1`

A better solution would be using the [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Use:

```
countBackground = indexPath.row % 4
if (countBackground == 0) {
    //you are in row 0, 4, 8, ... -> Red color
} else if (countBackground == 1) {
    //you are in row 1, 5, 9, ... -> Green color
} else if (countBackground == 2) {
    //you are in row 2, 6, 10, ... -> Orange color
} else if (countBackground == 3) {
    //you are in row 3, 7, 11, ... -> Yellow color
}
```